# Select data in the order of the column name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using the below code to fetch data. I want the order of the selected data in the order of id -> last_name -> first_name but the data return is in the order of id -> first_name -> last_name. Please help me find where I am going wrong. I am using rails 5

```
x=["id", "last_name", "first_name"]
@posts = Post.select(x.map(&:inspect).join(', '))

[#<Post:0x00007f82bba3
  id: 215,
  first_name: "Jack",
  last_name: "Wills">,
 #<Post:0x00007f82bba3
  id: 216,
  first_name: "Ross",
  last_name: "Denny">]
```

Comment: It returns in the correct order because it is ordered by id (215 then 216), there is no other ordering to be done as no 2 posts will have the same id. Please explain how you would expect this to be ordered otherwise?

Comment: @engineersmnky I am talking about the order of the column names. The query returns id -> first_name -> last_name but I want id -> last_name -> first_name, last_name and then first_name

Comment: Attributes are not "ordered". The reason you see them like this is simply because `first_name` comes before `last_name` in your table definition and thus in the inspection of the object. Can you please describe what the reasoning would be for this need? You could implement as `.map {|post| post.attributes.values_at(*x)}` but I think if you describe the reason others will provide you with better and more idiomatic guidance as to why this is not needed.

Comment: @engineersmnky Actually I using a Vuejs library which requires the data in this format

Comment: @engineersmnky can you suggest some solution?

Comment: how are you using the vuejs library? does it specifically need to be ordered differently in the object or could you just access it the way you need it on the frontend?

Comment: @Haumer it needs data in the order

Comment: humor me. seems like you could either just map it the way you want or access it the way you want on the frontend

Answer (score 1):

```
x=["id", "last_name", "first_name"]
@posts = Post.select(x.map(&:inspect).join(', '))
@posts = @posts.map{ |l| l.attributes.slice(*x)}
```

This is how I solved it.